# Passing address of non-local object to _autoreleasing parameter for write-back in SKPSMTPMessage.m using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, smtpclient, smtplib

I am new to iOS,I have Implemented Background mail using SMTP Server,While Integrating with Main Project I am getting (passing address of non-local object to _autoreleasing parameter for write-back) this error I don't know how to solve that ,I referred this  [link](http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2013/01/sending-e-mail-in-background-from-ios_25.html) to implement Background Mail. I have used this  SMTP library [link](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage)
Below line getting error,

```
[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:relayHost port:relayPort inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];
```

Answer (score 0):

Under ARC a parameter declared as:

```
SomeObjectType ** parameterName
```

has the implicit *ownership qualifier* of `__autoreleasing`:

```
SomeObjectType * __autoreleasing * parameterName
```

Such parameters are *out* parameters, that is they receive a value from the called method rather than pass a value to the called method, and the actual parameter must be the address of a *local* variable. This mechanism is referred to as *pass-by-writeback*.

The error message is telling you that one or both of addresses you have passed are not those of local variables, i.e. either or both of `inputStream` or `outputStream` are not local variables.

The simple fix is to introduce local variables to use for the parameters and after the call copy the returned values into your non-local variables:

```
NSInputStream *tempInputStream;
NSOutputStream *tempOutputStream;
[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:relayHost port:relayPort inputStream:&tempInputStream outputStream:&tempOutputStream];
// copy return values to non-local variables
inputStream = tempInputStream;
outputStream = tempOutputStream;
```

If you wish to understand the reasons why out parameters only accept local variables read [Passing to an out parameter by writeback](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#passing-to-an-out-parameter-by-writeback) in Apple's Clang documentation.

HTH